# SQL expression working with many-to-many to LINQ

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, asp.net-core

ASP CORE MVC application.

I have 2 tables:

```
public class StudentModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string ChineseName { get; set; }
    public string EnglishName { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthdayDate { get; set; }

    public List<StudentParent> StudentParent { get; set; }
    public List<StudentCourse> StudentCourse { get; set; }

    public StudentModel()
    {
        StudentParent = new List<StudentParent>();
        StudentCourse = new List<StudentCourse>();
    }
}
public class ParentModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public List<StudentParent> StudentParent { get; set; }

    public ParentModel()
    {
        StudentParent = new List<StudentParent>();
    }
}
```

With relation many-to-many.

```
 public class StudentParent
{
    public Guid StudentId { get; set; }
    public StudentModel Student { get; set; }



    public Guid ParentId { get; set; }
    public ParentModel Parent { get; set; }
}
```

The question is: **How to get Id from ParentModel table if I know student Id?**
In Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio I can execute this command and get what I want:

```
             SELECT ParentModels.Id
             FROM StudentModels
             LEFT OUTER JOIN StudentParent
             ON StudentModels.Id = StudentParent.StudentId
             LEFT OUTER JOIN ParentModels
             ON StudentParent.ParentId = ParentModels.Id
             WHERE StudentModels.Id = 'A1F38C12-AE65-464C-C489-08D814F4CDDC'
```

How to write this code in Visual Studio with LINQ?
I tried this instead:

```
Guid parentID = context.StudentModels.FromSqlRaw("SELECT ParentModels.Id FROM StudentModels LEFT OUTER JOIN StudentParent ON StudentModels.Id = StudentParent.StudentId LEFT OUTER JOIN ParentModels ON StudentParent.ParentId = ParentModels.Id WHERE StudentModels.Id = '{0}'", guid).FirstOrDefault();
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this being many-to-many, there could be more than 1 `ParentModel.Id` for each student.

This being said, you could find them like this:

```
IEnumerable<Guid> parentIds = context.ParentModels
    .Where(p => p.StudentParent
        .Any(sp => sp.Student.Id == new Guid("A1F38C12-AE65-464C-C489-08D814F4CDDC")))
    .Select(p => p.Id);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `sp.Student.Id == new Guid("A1F38C12-AE65-464C-C489-08D814F4CDDC")` ?

Comment: @mortb Yes it should.

Comment: Select returns an IQueryAble and not an IEnumerable. To send it to the db you need to add ToList() or ToListAsync()

Comment: @Mono I've simply provided the logic for defining the query. When and how to execute is an implementation detail. `parentIds` was declared as `IEnumerable` to emphasise that there could be more than one.

Answer (score 0):

In such complex query where you need to make a lot of joins most developers prefer query LINQ syntax. It seems to be easier to read and understand.

```
     IEnumerable<Guid> parentIds =
            (from sm in context.StudentModels
             join sp in context.StudentParent on sm.Id equals sp.StudentId
             join pm in context.ParantModels on sp.ParentId equals pm.Id
             where sm.Id == new Guid("A1F38C12-AE65-464C-C489-08D814F4CDDC")
             select pm.Id).ToList();
```

More info about query and method syntax you can find in [Miscrosoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq)